# HTTP Post from Postman working but not through browser

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, jersey, jax-rs

I am using JaxRS jersey for server and I have deployed it on aws. Http post request to server is working with postman but not with Http post apache client.
Following is my  Java for Rest service

```
@Path("/data")
public class MyResource {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<trackerdetails> getIt() {
        SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        trackerdetails user = new trackerdetails();
        List<trackerdetails> sendlist = (List<trackerdetails>) session.createQuery("from trackerdetails").list();

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return sendlist;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public trackerdetails putit(trackerdetails track) {
        track.setDate(new Date());
        SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction(); 

        session.save(track);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return track;
    }
```

Following is my trackerdetails class

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class trackerdetails {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int autoid;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String devicename;
    private Date date;
    public trackerdetails(){

    }
    public int getAutoid() {
        return autoid;
    }
    public void setAutoid(int autoid) {
        this.autoid = autoid;
    }
    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public String getDevicename() {
        return devicename;
    }
    public void setDevicename(String devicename) {
        this.devicename = devicename;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

Following is my Client side http post request

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("myurl");
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devicename", "vip"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", "hjksvn"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", "hello"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude","hi"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));


httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Host", "trackertest.herokuapp.com");


CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

try {
    System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
    System.out.println(response2.toString());
    HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
    // do something useful with the response body
    // and ensure it is fully consumed
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response2.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result1 = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result1.append(line);

        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("");
}
System.out.println(result1);
    EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
} finally {
    response2.close();
}
```

Following is my error status is 400
 Bad Request

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("myurl");` looks different plz change it to `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(myurl);`

Comment: the url is correct I meant that I have added the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your REST API expects request in `JSON` format but the way you are constructing request body using `NameValuePair` will not result in `JSON` format.

You should make a valid `JSON` request body either by using some libraries which can convert object into `JSON` like `Jackson` or you can manually construct `JSON` request body and then call your API.

Below is one way of manually constructing `JSON` request body -

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("myurl");

StringBuilder jsonBody = new StringBuilder();
jsonBody.append("{");
jsonBody.append("\"devicename\" : ").append("\"vip\"").append(",");
// Pass a valid date because on server side, you are using Date object for accepting it
jsonBody.append("\"date\" : ").append("\"2017-09-23\"").append(",");
jsonBody.append("\"latitude\" : ").append("\"vip\"").append(",");
jsonBody.append("\"longitude\" : ").append("\"vip\"");
jsonBody.append("}");

StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(jsonBody.toString(),"application/json","UTF-8");


httpPost.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);

httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Host", "trackertest.herokuapp.com");
// Rest code should remain same
```